# Include application names in alt+tab menu on Xfce 4.14

Tags: xfce

hitting Alt-tab on Xfce 4.14 displays shows the follow:

[image]

Notice how only one application includes the name? (In this case, "Thunar" is the only app labeled with its name)? I would like to make it so the application name is always displayed. Can you please show me how I can do this?

Comment: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15497